# The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have this code which normally works:

```
db.myTable.DeleteObject(myCurrent);
```

And I got this error:

```
The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.
```

The same ingredients IS in the table in the database.

I tried this:

```
db.myTable.Attach(myCurrent);
db.myTable.DeleteObject(myCurrent);
```

And I got another error:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The second exception means that you have `myCurrent` attached to or loaded into another context instance than `db`.

Comment: @Slauma but how is that possible?

Comment: It could happen if you didn't dispose an old context properly for example and `myCurrent` is still attached to it. Or you loaded `myCurrent` in context `db1` and then try to delete it with another context `db2`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The other answer didn't work, so here's how I fixed it.

Previously I had:

```
public void ok(myTable myCurrent)
{
    //delete entries from other tables in relationship with myTable
    db.myTables.DeleteObject(myCurrent);

}
```

I fixed it with this:

```
public void ok(int current_id)
{
    //delete entries from other tables in relationship with myTable
    var y = (from x in db.myTables where x.id == current_id select x).First();
    db.myTables.DeleteObject(y);

}
```

Comment: Yes, with ID it worked for me however I wanted to give an option to delete with the object ;    if (this.context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                this.dbSet.Attach(entity);
            }

            this.dbSet.Remove(entity); and it is not working.

Comment: This worked for me too. In my case the cause was that i was using a caching mechanism which obtained the object out of the cache in stead of from the database.

Comment: @petko_stankoski hey but when i type DeleteObject it's get error?

Answer (score 27):

The problem is you cannot delete (or remove) detached entities and cannot attach an entity twice. You need something like below.

```
var entry = db.Entry(myCurrent);
if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
    db.myTable.Attach(myCurrent);
db.myTable.Remove(myCurrent);
```

Comment: I think that checking if the object is attached can be substituted with `Find(Object[] keyValues)` method.

Answer (score 11):

if you just received model from edit or delete view by post or generated it yourself then EF doesn't know about it so you set its state to "Deleted" (or EntityState.Modified etc) to inform EF by:

```
//generate it yourself if not posted from edit/delete view
//var model = new Model { Id = 123 };

//set to delete
db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Deleted; // or EntityState.Modified for edit etc.
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4):

Although this question is an old question, But it may help another people with same error,

In my case, the problem was I Fetched data AsNoTracking, by removing AsNoTracking it solved.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/delete-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx

Here is the "disconnected" version, which I needed;

```
       Student stud = null;

        using (SchoolDBContext ctx = new SchoolDBContext())
        {
            stud = (from s in ctx.Students
                    where s.StudentName == "Student1"
                        select s).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        using (SchoolDBContext newCtx = new SchoolDBContext())
        {
            newCtx.Students.Attach(stud);
            newCtx.Students.DeleteObject(stud);
            //you can use ObjectStateManager also
            //newCtx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(stud, 
                                    System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
            int num = newCtx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to delete an object that is not fetched from the database table "Student".
Wrong way to delete object:

var objStudent= new Student();
 db.Student.Remove(objStudent);

So take care of this. Object to delete should come from the table

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I had been using two different DBContext instances for retriving data and update/remove. Then I have used the same instance for the all db actions in the same codeblock/method/class, then problem resolved

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here.
 I also tried its working :

```
dbEntities.Entry(CurrentObj).State = EntityState.Deleted;                
dbEntities.SaveChanges();
```